# Division of Large numbers

Tags: biginteger, division

Is there any faster method for division of large integers(having 1000 digits or more) other than the school method?

Comment: I assume @prashanthkvs means long division.

Comment: The basic division method we use for integers which we can simulate for large integers. I am asking this as I saw other methods like finding the inverse, but I am not sure if they will always give correct results.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia lists [multiple division algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(digital)). See [Computational complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) which lists [Schoolbook long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) as `O(n^2)` and [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(digital)#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division) as `M(n)` where `M` is the complexity of the multiplication algorithm used, which could be as good as `O(n log n 2^(`[`log*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm)`n))` asymptotically.

Note from the discussion of [one of the multiplication algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) that the best algorithm asymptotically is not necessarily the fastest for "small" inputs:

> In practice the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm starts to outperform older methods such as Karatsuba and Toom–Cook multiplication for numbers beyond 2^(2^15) to 2^(2^17) (10,000 to 40,000 decimal digits). The GNU Multi-Precision Library uses it for values of at least 1728 to 7808 64-bit words (111,000 to 500,000 decimal digits), depending on architecture. There is a Java implementation of Schönhage–Strassen which uses it above 74,000 decimal digits.