# Binomial coefficient with large integers in C

Tags: c, algorithm, biginteger, binomial-coefficients

Some time ago I created a big integer library, to compute the factorial of large integers (up to five million) using FFT and binary splitting.
Now I need to compute the binomial coefficent (n! /(k! *(n-k)!)) with big integers (something like n=10000 and k=4000)), and I need to realize a function that implements the diviosn between big integers, or even the inverse of a big integer.

So, I ask you which algorithm I can use to realize this function.

I post below the structure that represents a big int:

```
typedef struct{
double *arg;        
int  size;      
int nsize;      
} big_f;
```

Where "arg" is the polynomial rappresentation of a big int, "size" is the number of digits, "nsize" is the length of arg.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for your attention.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257612/division-of-large-numbers

Comment: TAOCP Vol.2, Sec 4.3.1, page 270

Comment: Checking just in case, do you need this to compute hypergeometric P-values? If so, I recommend using the GNU scientific library.

Comment: @micans
i need only to compute the binomial coefficent.
It is only for a project for a university exam.