# Implementation of Big numbers division

Tags: c++, c++11, long-integer, biginteger, division

I develop own big_int class. It is a study task. I implemented `+`, `-`, and `*` ops. It works well and fast. But I have some troubles with implementation of big numbers division.

I implemented division, as the difference between the numbers (pseudocode):

```
big_int division (big_int first_number, big_int second_number) {
    big_int counter = 0
    while (second_number <= first_number) {
        first_number -= second_number;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

It works only for small numbers. But my test numbers have length not greater than 100.

I present my number as array with `base = 10`. For example, `113` equal to `number[3] = {1, 1, 3};`

Comment: If it only works with small numbers, and your division is done in terms of `-=`, then maybe your `-=` isn't working as well as you say it does.  Wait, shouldnt that be `-=` and not `=-`? (looking at your code more carefully).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it works for big numbers too. But It works very, very slow.

Comment: Well, no one will know until you post your code as to what you're doing.  But look at my comment and look at your code again.  Are you sure you're using the right operation between the `first_number` and `second_number`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yeah, I did typo.

Comment: Let's see your `operator -`, and `operator -=`.  If you implemented them smartly, then `operator -` should be implemented in terms of `operator -=`.  But what is your real question?  Is it that it's running slow or it doesn't work at all?

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, you are right. Anyway, my implementation of division works correctly, but it is slow. I'm looking for another algorithm for my task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division of Large numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257612/division-of-large-numbers)

Comment: If you have TAOCP handy, take a look at Algorithm D in vol. 2.

Comment: Just curious, Why are you not using bit shift? much faster than a while loop!